# When do we usually map all partitions to the same filegroup?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I was studying "Partition Function" and "Partition Schema" in SQL-Server in MSDN. I found this syntax that maps all partitions to the same filegroup.
For example:

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION myRangePF3 (int)  
AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES (1, 100, 1000);  
GO  
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME myRangePS3  
AS PARTITION myRangePF3  
ALL TO ( test1fg );
```

My question is that what is the key point in doing this?
Is this even called partitioning???
When do we usually map all partitions to the same filegroup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Partitioning a table with all of the partitions on the same filegroup gives you the following benefits:

- Partition elimination in queries
- Ability to partition switch within the filegroup
- Rowgroups cannot be split across partitions for CCIs which can lead to better rowgroup elimination in queries
- Incremental statistics as of SQL Server 2014
- Other maintenance operations can be done at the partition level such as rebuilds
- Different behavior for parallel scans which can be helpful in some cases.

These benefits are also present when putting partitions on different filegroups, except when noted otherwise.

One reason to put partitions on different filegroups is when you want to put older data on a filegroup that's mapped to a slower tier of storage.

Answer (score 0):

> Let’s nerd out for a bit on what table partitioning does in SQL
>   Server. First of all, this is an Enterprise Edition feature.
>   (Cha-ching! $$$.)  You can test it in developer edition, but if you
>   want to use it in production, you gotta make sure it’s worth the
>   licensing costs as well as your time.
>
> Table partitioning allows tables or indexes to be stored in multiple
>   physical sections— a partitioned index is like one large index made up
>   of multiple little indexes. Each chunk, or partition, has the same
>   columns– just a different range of rows. Table partitioning is
>   “transparent”. This means a partitioned heap, clustered index, or
>   non-clustered index can be referenced as a single structure although
>   it’s stored in independent physical partitions. In other words, in
>   theory you don’t need to change any code in the calling applications.
>   (Is this true in reality? More on this later.)

**check this out it might be useful -**
https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/03/how-decide-if-should-use-table-partitioning/

Comment: Thank you for your practical and beautiful comment but the website wont open it has problem.

Comment: I think "*First of all, this is an Enterprise Edition feature*" is no longer true with SQL Server 2016